# 403 on any localhost resource

Tags: permissions, apache-httpd

Irrespective of which resource on `localhost` I request, I get the [403 Forbidden](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_403) HTTP error. I have Apache (included in Debian 10 distribution), and `cat /var/log/apache2/error.log` gives me this relevant line:

```
[Sun Aug 09 22:55:01.943309 2020] [authz_core:error] [pid 3568] [client ::1:48672] AH01630: client denied by server configuration: /home/morten/NetBeansProjects
```

I might provide `localhost` or `localhost/existing_url` or `localhost/wrong_url` -- all give me the same HTTP 403 error and the same type of error log entry.

**Permissions:**

```
$ ls -l | grep NetBeansProjects
    drwxr-xr-x  4 morten morten      4096 aug  9 20:25 NetBeansProjects
```

and

```
$ ls -l Dropbox/NetBeansProjects/
    totalt 620
    drwxr-xr-x 3 morten morten   4096 aug  9 20:25 bedom
    drwxr-xr-x 3 morten morten   4096 aug  2 17:05 ElevMonitorering
    -rwxrwxrwx 1 morten morten      5 aug  6 09:49 index.html
```

and

```
 ls -l Dropbox/NetBeansProjects/bedom/
totalt 8
-rwxr-xr-x 1 morten morten  406 aug  9 20:27 index.php
drwxr-xr-x 3 morten morten 4096 aug  9 20:25 nbproject
```

In Apache2, `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf` shows the following (selected) lines:

```
<Directory />
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Require all denied
</Directory>

<Directory /usr/share>
        AllowOverride None
        Require all granted
</Directory>

# <Directory /var/www/>
<Directory /home/morten/Dropbox/NetBeansProjects>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Require all granted
</Directory>
```

while `/etc/apache2/sites-available/default-ssl.conf` has:

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
        <VirtualHost _default_:443>
                ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

                DocumentRoot /home/morten/Dropbox/NetBeansProjects # /var/www/html
```

and, in parallel, `/etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf` shows:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        DocumentRoot /home/morten/NetBeansProjects
```

So my question is: What do I need to correct to get the content of URLs such as `localhost/index.php` (instead of error 403)?

### Edit

After adding `localhost.localdomain` according to [this answer](https://serverfault.com/q/185954), only the `http://localhost/index.php` gives me trouble, but I might not need that index file in production purposes, so I'll leave this question. I consider it solved insofar the needed `http://localhost/bedom/index.php` responses as wanted. See my own comments to myself. Ashamed to admit, that the 404 was **totally trivial**: While `index.html` existed, I requested `index.php` in `localhost` folder root ...

Comment: Apache version is `apache2 (2.4.38-3+deb10u3) ` according to https://packages.debian.org/buster/apache2 (I do not know how to ask my system to give version).

Comment: I run the webserver locally on my own machine, testing an application before I let NetBeans 12 export it to production site online.

Comment: I think I have been through the [Apache Wiki on  ClientDeniedByServerConfiguration](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/HTTPD/ClientDeniedByServerConfiguration), but I must miss something...

Comment: The above mentioned ClientDeniedByServerConfiguration gives a hint. The `error.log` shows a *non-existent path**. From [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/864386/4832261), I get two hits, located to a file: `find /etc/apache2/ -name *.conf -exec grep \/home\/morten\/NetBeansProjects {} +` outputting:
`/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf:        DocumentRoot /home/morten/NetBeansProjects`

Comment: It appeard, that the `Dropbox` folder did not have sufficient permissions: `[Mon Aug 10 09:21:45.996942 2020] [core:error] [pid 3955] (13)Permission denied: [client ::1:50302] AH00035: access to /index.php denied (filesystem path '/home/morten/Dropbox/NetBeansProjects') because search permissions are missing on a component of the path` - this error was eliminated by `chmod a+rx Dropbox`: Now `[Mon Aug 10 09:24:44.788580 2020] [php7:error] [pid 4018] [client ::1:50322] script '/home/morten/Dropbox/NetBeansProjects/index.php' not found or unable to stat` ...

Comment: Then I found [this SO on 'unable to stat' error](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57821820/4832261). `error.log` entry says`[Mon Aug 10 09:24:44.788580 2020] [php7:error] [pid 4018] [client ::1:50322] script '/home/morten/Dropbox/NetBeansProjects/index.php' not found or unable to stat` but that file **esixts** and has all permissions: `$ ls -l Dropbox/NetBeansProjects/index.html`gives me `-rwxrwxrwx 1 morten morten 5 aug  6 09:49 Dropbox/NetBeansProjects/index.html`

Comment: Now the 403 error is gone. For `localhost/index.php`, I now get error 404, though. but for `localhost/bedom/index.php` and `localhost/ElevMonitorering/index.php`, I get  displayed "Hello World!" just like I want it. Same permissions to the three `index.php` files: `-rwxr-xr-x`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All folders, the **entire path** must have permission for all, or to be precise: *the web server daemon*, to read and execute. That is, the path `/home/morten/NetBeansProjects` must show like this:

```
ls -l / | grep home
drwxr-xr-x   3 root root  4096 maj 27 22:08 home
$ ls -l /home | grep morten
drwxr-xr-x 28 morten morten 4096 aug 10 22:23 morten
$ ls -l /home/morten | grep Dropbox
drwxr-xr-x 32 morten morten   4096 aug 10 22:25 Dropbox
$ ls -l /home/morten/Dropbox/ | grep NetBeansProjects
drwxr-xr-x  4 morten morten      4096 aug  9 20:25 NetBeansProjects
```

with `r` and `x` set for both owner, group and other. That was to be corrected in my setup mentioned in the question.

Then, the file `/etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf` should hold the correct path to the web server root in the `DocumentRoot` directive.

Furthermore, the `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf` file should refer to the same folder as

```
<Directory /home/morten/Dropbox/NetBeansProjects>
```

I think that will be all to fix the 403.